Solving an "impossible" integral, $\int \frac{dx}{a^{x^2}+b^{x^2}} $
First a saw this problem
$$\int \frac{dx}{a^{x^2}+b^{x^2}} $$
where a,b are natural numbers
This problem would be easier if $a=b$
then error function appears here
I have tried with Wolfram alpha but he show me that
"(no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions)"
But I was wondering is there a solution when $a≠b$ , at least when the interval from $[-∞,∞]$
Could anybody help or give a hints to solve?

are you asking for special a,b or in general for all? There are solutions for special cases of course (a=1,b=0 e.g)

$$\int \frac{1}{a^{x^2}+b^{x^2}} , dx=\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^m \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}\left(x \sqrt{\ln (a)+m \ln (a)-m \ln (b)}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\ln
(a)+m \ln (a)-m \ln (b)}}+c$$

Assuming $a$ and $b$ are real numbers so that $0 < a < b$ and $b > 1$, write $\alpha = \log a$ and $\beta = \log b$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^{x^2} + b^{x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\beta x^2}}{1 + e^{-(\beta - \alpha) x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(\beta + (n-1)(\beta - \alpha)) x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\beta + (n-1)(\beta - \alpha)}}
\end{align*}
This series can be written in terms of Hurwitz zeta function.

If you are optimistic, at least for $b$ close to $a$,
$$\frac{1}{a^{x^2}+b^{x^2}}=\frac{1}{2}a^{-x^2}-\frac{1}{4a} x^2 a^{-x^2}(b-a)+\frac{1}{8a^2} x^2 a^{-x^2}(b-a)^2+$$
$$\frac{1}{48a^3} x^2 \left(x^4-4\right) a^{-x^2}(b-a)^3-\frac{1}{32a^4} x^2 \left(x^4-2\right) a^{-x^2}(b-a)^4+O\left((b-a)^5\right)$$ to face integrals
$$I_n=\int x^{2n}a^{-x^2}\,dx=-\frac 12 x^{2n+1}\,\,E_{\frac{1}{2}-n}\left(x^2 \log (a)\right)$$  which could write in very different manners.
Edit
Assuming $a>1$
$$J_n=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^{2n}\,a^{-x^2}\,dx=\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)} { \log ^{n+\frac{1}{2}}(a)}$$
If $b=a+1$, using the above truncated series, the result is
$$I(a)=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{dx}{a^{x^2}+(a+1)^{x^2}} \, =\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2 \sqrt{\log (a)}}(1+A+B)$$ where
$$A=-\frac{12 a^3-6 a^2+4 a-3}{48 a^4 \log (a)}\qquad \text{and}\qquad B=\frac{5 (2 a-3)}{128 a^4 \log ^3(a)}$$ which seems to be decent
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & \text{estimate} & \text{solution}\\
 2 & 0.91830058 & 0.91828474 \\
 3 & 0.79121266 & 0.79121264 \\
 4 & 0.72264027 & 0.72264036 \\
 5 & 0.67886199 & 0.67886206 \\
 6 & 0.64786508 & 0.64786511 \\
 7 & 0.62442423 & 0.62442424 \\
 8 & 0.60587663 & 0.60587662 \\
 9 & 0.59070933 & 0.59071460 \\
 10 & 0.57799223 & 0.57799893 \\
 11 & 0.56711842 & 0.56711840 \\
 12 & 0.55767295 & 0.55767293 \\
 13 & 0.54936125 & 0.54936124 \\
 14 & 0.54196768 & 0.54196767 \\
 15 & 0.53533024 & 0.53533023 \\
 16 & 0.52932453 & 0.52932453 \\
 17 & 0.52385324 & 0.52385323 \\
 18 & 0.51883895 & 0.51883895 \\
 19 & 0.51421923 & 0.51421924 \\
 20 & 0.50994307 & 0.50994307 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Thanks but where did this sum come from?

@3eKe3m. This is a Taylor series

I know but I mean how did you derive it?

@3eKe3m. Take the denominator, convert to exponentials, perform the series and then long division. By the way, I added some results for $b=a+1$. Cheers :-)
